# Matching a certain pattern in xslt

Tags: xslt

i have an xml like:

```
<test>
    <email>youyue19910410@gmail.com</email>
<test>
```

The question is how can I write the test condition when I want to check whether this email is valid, i.e., the email address should follow the pattern xxxxx@xxx.com.

I wrote the following xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:variable name="email"><xsl:value-of select="/test/email"/></xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="test">
     <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="need your help here!">
               <message>This email is valid!</message>
          <xsl:otherwise>
               <message>This email is not valid</message>
          </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Well only XSLT 2.0 and later has regular expression matching with the `matches` function. Do you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or like XmlPrime? As for XSLT 1.0, there is a `contains` function which would allow you to check for `<xsl:template match="test/email[contains(., '@')]">...</xsl:template>` and with some substring you could test whether the last four letters are `.com`. Whether any of that is a good idea to find valid email addresses is a different question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I use XSLT 1.0. I will try contains and ends with function. Thanks again!